# How do I Capture keyboard/mouse events with my application in focus?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'm building a synergy like app for Mac OS, that captures keyboard/mouse and sends them to a remote computer.

I wish to capture all user keyboard and mouse events, while my NSWindow is in focus (if possible, while not in focus would be nicer). the catch is - I don't want system shortcuts like CMD+Tab or CMD+Q to interrupt me, I wish to handle them before the windowing system does, so that my app won't loose focus. Same for mouse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this - [Cocoa Event-Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @eyalw You can look into using CGEventTap to detect/change/cancel key events, including global events like Cmd+Tab.